# How to show children terms of parent terms in taxonomy?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Ok this thing is driving me completely haywire! I think this question has been asked before in some ways but I seem to be too dumb to tweak those to my requirement.

I've created a taxonomy vocabulary named "Brands" of products like so

Level 1: Brand names like Logitech, Gigabyte etc.

Level 2: Product categories like mice, keyboards, headphones etc inside each brand.

Level 3: The actual products inside each categories.

These levels can go deeper if necessary. Like in mice there can be wireless and standard ones. I hope I'm being clear. I've also created a menu from this taxonomy by using "Taxonomy Menu" and "Superfish" modules.

Now what I want is that when I click a menu entry (could be of any level) the page loaded should list it's children inside it. Like clicking Gigabyte should list only the names of categories of products inside the page not the actual products. I've gone through many insane combinations of options in views but to no use. So far I've only managed to show product teasers on every level but that's not what I want.

I want to do things the way it's done on the following site:
http://www.shophive.com/

I'm using Drupal 7 by the way.

Please please please help me with this as I'm on a deadline! :(

Comment: Or if this can be done in some other completely different way apart from views then please do let me know about it.

Comment: Have you tried simple changing the "style" of your view? [This video does a view page of vocabulary links](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/85),  as shown at start and even though it's done with cck+views the concept is more or less the same with D7 and views. Good-luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do this.

Use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to override `term_view`.

Edit the overridden `term_view` panel.  Add a new variant with the default settings.  In the `Content` section, add content.  You want a `List of related terms`, which can be found under `Taxonomy term`.  You can set this to be the `Child terms` of the `Term being viewed`.

Comment: Thanks for response! I don't see term_view in Panels. Are you referring to Taxonomy Term template? If so then I don't see term_view there either..

Comment: Yes, I meant the `Taxonomy Term template`.  `term_view` is the machine name; they are the same thing.  Just go to the `Content` section on the `Taxonomy Term template` and the rest of the instructions should be the same.

Comment: I apologize for being an idiot but there is no 'Content' section inside the template. There are 3 sections there namely Summary, Variant and Settings. I've tried adding a variant but I don't understand what to do with it. Am I missing an extra module?

Comment: Ah, you'll have to create a variant first.

Comment: Ok I've followed your instructions precisely and saved my changes. Are these changes supposed to show up automatically or do I have to do something else after that? I'm seeing no effect on my taxonomy pages..

Comment: It depends on how your taxonomy pages are configured.  If you're overriding them with Views as well, you should disable that view temporarily.  You'll also need to make sure they have the path that is being overridden.  They should show up as soon as you have everything correctly configured.

Comment: O my lord it worked! I'm finally relieved of two weeks of torture! Thank you very much Patrick. If you were here I would have given you a big wet kiss! :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how you are configured, but I would try using [taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) for the configuration walk-through, [this is a good help page](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-add-block-menu-tags-or-other-taxonomy-terms-drupal-site).

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for response! The link you referred me to is creating blocks to do something entirely different. I need to create a page not a block to list my children terms. Do you have any other suggestions?