# Show all terms that are children of term with argument tid

Tags: views

I need a view that shows all terms that are children of the argument tid.

```
term 1
-term 2
-term 3
term 4
-term 5
```

view/4 should return term 5

I must be missing something fundamental because no matter how I mess with contextual filters and relationships I never come close to actually filtering my results by the context.

Comment: The best way I've found was courtesy of [Patrick Kenny](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/5147/patrick-kenny) on the answer he posted [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30134/how-to-show-children-terms-of-parent-terms-in-taxonomy). It does however require Panels. If it's good for you then head over there and throw him an upvote ;-)

Comment: This view will be loaded into another view as a field, plus it shouldn't be too hard (It's just a `WHERE` clause pulled straight from the url)

Comment: Would the setup [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324509/drupal-on-term-page-show-child-terms) help at all?

Comment: Great! The difference was I was using a "parent term" context and I needed a "term id" one. Post it as an answer and I'll tick you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Answers that are just links are frowned upon, but the answer in my comment can be found here on StackOverflow [Drupal - On term page show child terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324509/drupal-on-term-page-show-child-terms).

The image on that answer is also posted below:

[image: Original answer image posted on StackOverflow]

It would be good if people could head to the original answer and throw the author an upvote if this is helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a contextual filter for taxonomy term with depth modifier, it should work, e.g terms/1/1